# Unable to display alert when changing from one view to another in TabBar Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using a tab bar controller in my application.

I can change the view by clicking the buttons on the tab, but when I click the tab button it should display an alert for confirmation from the end user, like: *"You should leave this page"*.

If *"Yes"*, then navigate, otherwise it should stay on the same page...

The alert does not show up, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code for alertview, call this in a method which gets called after tab button is clicked....And add UIAlertView delegate

```
     UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"You should leave this page" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
     [myAlert show];
     [myAlert release];
```

Also override the method

```
       - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
             if(actionSheet==myAlert){
                if (buttonIndex == 0)
                {
                //here call the corresponding page
                 }
                 }
         else
         {
                    //Do nothing
        NSLog(@"cancel");
         }

      }
```

Comment: I want this alert only when i am on some specific view..In my application there are 5 tab and in all tabbar i have add 1 navigation controller...i dont need alert every time when i click on tabbaritem Just when i am on some important View...Thank you!!

Comment: Then in that function just check which view is getting called and accordingly show alert.....Get all the controllers in an array like this    array = [[self tabBarController] viewControllers]; and then check if the controller which is to be pushed  [[array objectAtIndex:0]sKindOfClass:[YourClassName class]] if this satisfies for then show alert..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"myMSg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel"];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];

   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
      if (buttonIndex == 0)
      {
          //Code for OK button i.e go to the next tab bar
      }
       if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
           //Code for cancel button i.e dont load the next tab bar.
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create tab bar controller programmatically instead of creating them in xib file as below

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    // set up a local nav controller which we will reuse for each view controller
    UINavigationController *localNavigationController;
    // create tab bar controller and array to hold the view controllers
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

// setup the first view controller (Root view controller)
RootViewController *myViewController;
myViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];

// create the nav controller and add the root view controller as its first view
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

// add the new nav controller (with the root view controller inside it)
// to the array of controllers
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

// release since we are done with this for now
[localNavigationController release];
[myViewController release];

// setup the first view controller just like the first 
ResortsListViewController *resortsListViewController;
resortsListViewController = [[ResortsListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResortsListView" bundle:nil];
resortsListViewController.title = @"Category1";
resortsListViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
resortsListViewController.navigationItem.title=@"a1";
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:resortsListViewController];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController]; 
[localNavigationController release];

// setup the second view controller just like the first 
RootViewController *rootViewController;
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
rootViewController.title = @"a2";
rootViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
resortsListViewController.navigationItem.title=@"a2";
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController]; 
[localNavigationController release];

// setup the third view controller just like the first 
RootViewController *rootViewController;
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
rootViewController.title = @"a3";
rootViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
rootViewController.navigationItem.title=@"ay3";
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController]; 
[localNavigationController release];

[rootViewController release];

// load up our tab bar controller with the view controllers
tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;

// release the array because the tab bar controller now has it
[localControllersArray release];

// add the tabBarController as a subview in the window
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

// need this last line to display the window (and tab bar controller)
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

& after that use alert view for each button:

```
UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Do you want to leave this page1" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
     [Alert show];
     [Alert release];
     [Alert setTag:1];
```

UIAlertView *Alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Do you want to leave this page2" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
         [Alert show];
         [Alert release];
         [Alert setTag:2];

& check which button is pressed by :

```
   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
     if ([alertView tag] == 1) 
      if (buttonIndex == 0)
      {
          //Code for OK button i.e go to the next tab bar
      }
       if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
           //Code for cancel button i.e dont load the next tab bar.
         }
    }
```